# Advice on Learning SharePoint Content Mangement

Tags: tutorials

What would you suggest is the best way to get up to speed (preferably, fast track) to learning how to manage content in SharePoint?  I'm a quick learn, years of experience writing...just need something AFFORDABLE to get me "good to go" in SP content management.  Advice???

Answer (score 0):

Want affordable, search youtube.  Tons of great how tos and explainers on SharePoint.  Just like PowerShell; search terms you learn in one video to find others on more in depth topics.